# Laravel - Testing mailable not working in phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have one issue and I hope you can help me, in the browser, my app works fine, but if I try to test it in phpunit, it is not passing the test.

In my controller I have this:

```
...
  Mail::send(new ProjectCreated($project));
 ...
```

This is my test:

ProjectTest.php:

```
...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\ProjectCreated;

class ProjectTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_an_email_is_sent_when_a_project_is_submitted()
    {                
        //given        
        Mail::fake();        

        // when
        $project = Project::factory()->make();          

        $response = $this->post(route('projects.store'), $project->toArray());            

        //then
        $response->assertOk();
        Mail::assertSent(ProjectCreated::class);    

    }

}
```

Phpunit message:

> The expected [App\Mail\ProjectCreated] mailable was not sent. Failed
> asserting that false is true.

it is so strange, when I am developing this app I am using mailtrap, Even I put the same variables in the phpunit.xml But the error remains. What can I do? thank you.

Comment: Could be any number of things; first thing I would be doing is assertions on the result from the post. Make sure it returns the expected response code, stores the object in the database, etc.

Comment: Your are right, so I test the result of the response, $response->assertOk();, now I am getting this error: This API call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret API key. You can find a list of your API keys at... . So stripe was responsible for not making the test pass. but now, I added <server name="STRIPE_SECRET" value="sk_test_"/> the same I have in my .env file, but the error remains.

Comment: Do you really want to be making live API requests during your feature tests?

Comment: Not really, but I was just following the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#testing , then, what could I do?